# readFile and store as a List

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a file with multiple list of (String,String,Int):

```
[("aaa","aaaaaaaa",13),("asdasdasd","asdea",13)]
```

and I need to store it in a variable, I have this:

```
xfx = do {     
text <- readFile "textlist";   
let   
x=3 -- nothing   
in function text   
}
```

But function receives *Char* instead of that data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contains only *one* list, then you can just call `read` on the result of `readFile`:

```
parseFile :: IO [(String,String,Int)]
parseFile = do s <- readFile "textlist"
               return (read s)
```

Comment: But the type given is _IO [(String,String,Int)]_ and I can't use it in the other function

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg: you can't do file IO without getting into the IO monad.